# How to open SslSocketConnector to be accesible from outside

Tags: java, https

In my app I create SslSocketConnector following way:

```
    SslSocketConnector connector = new SslSocketConnector();
    connector.setKeystore(certificatePath);
    connector.setPassword(certificatePassword);
    connector.setKeyPassword(certificatePassword);
    connector.setTruststore(certificatePath);
    connector.setTrustPassword(certificatePassword);
    connector.setPort(8805);
    connector.setHost("127.0.0.1");
```

Problem is that I can't access it from the outside of my server. Eg: calling https://mydomain.cz:8805 will give me Error: connect ECONNREFUSED.

When I check lsof, I see:

```
java      18588            root   42u  IPv4 4608979      0t0  TCP *:8443 (LISTEN)
java      18588            root   51u  IPv4 4610607      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8805 (LISTEN)
```

I guess whole problem is that I need ***:8805** and not current **127.0.0.1:8805**. (Same as anothe app have it on line above).

Do you know please how to achieve that?

Comment: Which `SslSocketConnector` class are you talking about?  This is not a Java SE class ... and there is more than one 3rd-party class with this name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP must be **0.0.0.0**

```
SslSocketConnector connector = new SslSocketConnector();
connector.setKeystore(certificatePath);
connector.setPassword(certificatePassword);
connector.setKeyPassword(certificatePassword);
connector.setTruststore(certificatePath);
connector.setTrustPassword(certificatePassword);
connector.setPort(8805);
connector.setHost("0.0.0.0");
```

Comment: You should explain **why** it should be `0.0.0.0`.